# BlackBerry 10: Cascades and ForeignWindow

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I am using the Cascades UI and I need to use ForeignWindow in order to develop a control which will show an image will be able to zoom and pan in it. The ImageView control simply is incapable of doing this.

My question is: how and where am I supposed to handle touch events (in order to pan or zoom) for the window I am going to use as ForeignWindow.
Regarding that unlike the native SDK which uses an event loop, Cascades applications use App as a main class, so where am I supposed to handle the screen_event_t and/or gesture events I would normally handle if I were developing in Native for a window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cascades you can add your code inside the APP class which is main class. You can add method inside the APP.cpp file and it will works.

Comment: Care to provide an example for handling ForeignWindow events in such scenario?

Comment: Hi,From this link you can find ForeignWindow example. https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Community-Samples/tree/master/HelloCamera